# Simplify pretty-printing of naturals

Tags: isabelle

Let's say I wrote a function for reversing a list. I want to test it out using the `value` command, just to assure myself that I probably got it right. But the output looks horrible:

```
value "reverse [1,8,3]"
> "[1 + 1 + 1, 1 + 1 + (1 + 1) + (1 + 1 + (1 + 1)), 1]" :: "'a list"
```

If I tell Isabelle to treat those numeric characters as naturals, the output is even worse:

```
value "reverse [1::nat,8,3]"
> "[Suc (Suc (Suc 0)), Suc (Suc (Suc (Suc (Suc (Suc (Suc (Suc 0))))))), Suc 0]" :: "nat list"
```

Sometimes I resort to using strings, but that's looks a bit funny with all those apostrophes everywhere:

```
value "reverse [''1'',''8'',''3'']"
> "[''3'', ''8'', ''1'']" :: "char list list"
```

Can I instruct Isabelle's pretty-printer to print `Suc (Suc (Suc 0))` as `3`, and so on? Perhaps by giving some magical incantation to the `syntax` or `translations` commands?

---

Here's my complete example, in case you'd like to paste it into Isabelle:

```
theory Scratch imports Main begin

fun reverse where 
  "reverse [] = []"
| "reverse (x#xs) = reverse xs @ [x]"

value "reverse [1,8,3]"
value "reverse [1::nat,8,3]"
value "reverse [''1'',''8'',''3'']"

end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer:** My first thought is to use type `int`, since (unlike `nat`) its code generator setup uses a binary numeral representation by default.

Importing `"~~/src/HOL/Library/Code_Target_Nat"`, as naT suggests, is also a good idea if you don't want to use the `Suc` representation for type `nat`.

**Explanation:** Numerals in Isabelle are encoded using constructors defined in `Num.thy`; e.g. `5` is an abbreviation for `numeral (Bit1 (Bit0 One))`. Here `One`, `Bit0` and `Bit1` are constructors of type `num`. `numeral` is overloaded, and works for any type with a `1` and an associative `+`. Here are the code equations for `numeral`:

```
lemma numeral_code [code]:
  "numeral One = 1"
  "numeral (Bit0 n) = (let m = numeral n in m + m)"
  "numeral (Bit1 n) = (let m = numeral n in m + m + 1)"
```

If we generate code for `5::'a::numeral`, then `1` and `+` on type `'a` are treated as uninterpreted constants, so they remain in the output: `(1 + 1) + (1 + 1) + 1`.

Generating code for `5::nat` works the same, except we *do* have code for `1` and `+` on type `nat`, in terms of `Suc`. Thus `(1 + 1) + (1 + 1) + 1` reduces further to `Suc (Suc (Suc (Suc (Suc 0))))`.

Type `int` works differently. The code generator setup in `Int.thy` uses three constructor functions for type `int`: `Pos` and `Neg` of type `num => int`, as well as `0`. A `code_abbrev` declaration causes each occurrence of `numeral` at type `num => int` to be replaced by `Pos` during code generation. After the code is run, `Pos` is then turned back into `numeral` before Isabelle displays the result. Thus `5::int` evaluates to just `5`.

**Special code setup theories:** `src/HOL/Library` contains a few different theories for customizing code generation for numerals.

- `"~~/src/HOL/Library/Code_Target_Nat"` tells the code generator to use the target language's (e.g. SML or Haskell's) built-in numerals for type `nat`. For example, `5::nat` is usually translated to SML as `numeral (Bit1 (Bit0 One))`; however, with this library loaded it gets translated as `5` in SML. Results of `value` are translated back into the Isabelle numeral representation afterward.
- `"~~/src/HOL/Library/Code_Target_Int"` is the same, but for type `int` instead of `nat`.
- `"~~/src/HOL/Library/Code_Target_Numeral"` simply loads both of the previous two libraries. It only affects types `nat` and `int`, not any other types in class `numeral`.
- `"~~/src/HOL/Library/Code_Binary_Nat"` configures `nat` in the same style as the default code setup for `int`: with constructors `0` and `nat_of_num::num => nat` and a `code_abbrev` declaration. With this library, `value "5::nat"` also returns `5`.

Comment: Brian, thanks. I wouldn't have known that `Code_Binary_Nat` was the right one to use to get rid of `Suc`. Also, I've seen the `[code]` rules in Num.thy, but I've been ignoring them, and didn't relate them to all this, or even to `value`, so now there's one more part of the puzzle that's making sense.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** I hope my answer here doesn't prevent Brian Huffman or Florian Haftmann from giving an answer. If it does, that would be a bad thing. Hopefully, I'm just doing some gofer work to set either of them up.

**Short answer 1:** The pertinent mailing list email is [Re: [isabelle] value no longer pretty-prints numbers of type nat](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/fa.isabelle/value%2420no%2420longer%2420pretty-prints%2420numbers/fa.isabelle/oWgWYURJ1BA/Kg9nfAwyMosJ).

**Short answer 2:** A solution for `nat` is to import `"~~/src/HOL/Library/Code_Target_Nat"`. Because I'm not clear on the details of how `numeral` and `num` are completely tied into HOL at the low level, the solution I'm giving you is not necessarily a good and final solution.

A big part of my answer here is partly to say, before Brian Huffman or Florian Haftmann get here, who are the authors of [Num.thy](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/801a72ad52d3/src/HOL/Num.thy), "I'm interested in this too, because it's related to `numeral`, which is a powerful part of HOL. The more info I have about the intricacies of using `numeral`, the better".

Basically, they made a design choice change for Isabelle2013-1, which is to have the default for `nat` and `numeral` be represented in a successor form. That's what the mailing list email is about.

If you use `declare[[show_sorts=true]]`, you will see that your `value "reverse [1,8,3]"` is using type class `numeral`. I mention that because I've been putting a lot of effort into trying to learn about `numeral`, and even with concrete types, such as `nat` and `int`, the use of constants such as `44` and `5` involve `numeral`, at least for the input. And even with a concrete type like `nat`, `numeral` can be involved in `simp` rules that are being used.

Before saying more, one way to get nice `nat` output for `value "reverse [1::nat,8,3]"` is, again, to use the following import:

```
"~~/src/HOL/Library/Code_Target_Nat"
```

The reason I'm interested in your question is because that's just a plug-n-play solution I saw by Andreas Lochbihler in that email.

I can't get `value "reverse [1,8,3]"` to not use sums of 1 by importing this:

```
"~~/src/HOL/Library/Code_Target_Numeral"
```

So, I want to know about how to get `numeral` to be in that nice form we love to see.

Anyway, `numeral` is at the core of using number constants. Consider this:

```
lemma "(3::nat) = z"
using[[simp_trace, simp_trace_depth_limit=100, linarith_trace, rule_trace]]
using[[blast_trace, blast_stats]]
apply simp
oops
```

Part of the simp trace is this:

```
[1]SIMPLIFIER INVOKED ON THE FOLLOWING TERM:
3 = z 
[1]Procedure "Num.reorient_numeral" produced rewrite rule:
?a1 = ?b1 ≡ ?b1 = ?a1 
[1]Applying instance of rewrite rule
?a1 = ?b1 ≡ ?b1 = ?a1 
[1]Rewriting:
3 = z ≡ z = 3
```

If you look at simp traces involving number constants, you'll see that `Num` rules show up a lot, which come from that most excellent of [Num.thy](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/801a72ad52d3/src/HOL/Num.thy).

Comment: Thanks Gottfried. I followed the first link you gave, and it gave me the idea to replace `nat` with `int`. That worked out great, and I don't mind using integers instead of naturals in my example. If you could make explicit the suggestion of using `int` instead of `nat`, then I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @John, that's good to know. I didn't read that about ints. I'd prefer you don't accept my question. I'd like to see the two devs I mentioned add something that can give us some insight into what's going on. But they're busy people, so maybe they will, and maybe they won't.