# Isabelle return numbers instead of Suc(Suc( ... 0 ))

Tags: isabelle

When I use `value` to find out some value of a function that returns natural numbers, I always obtain the answer in the form of iterated Successor functions of 0, i.e., `Suc(Suc( ... 0 ))` which can be hard to read sometimes. 
Is there a way to output directly the number that Isabelle returns?

Comment: This sounds like the value isn't evaluated; it's a thunk. I don't know Isabelle, but it looks like you need to force evaluation.

Comment: Have you tried the answers here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22687646/simplify-pretty-printing-of-naturals

Answer (score 3):

This is something I wanted to fix some time ago but apparently I forgot. Carcigenate's guess is incorrect; this is indeed the fully evaluated result. The problem is just that natural numbers are printed in this unwieldy way.

You can do the following things:

1. The easiest way is to convert the number to an integer, i.e. instead of `value "foo x y z"` (where `foo x y z` is the expression of type `nat` that you want to eavluate) you write `value "int (foo x y z)"`.
2. You can add `~~/src/HOL/Library/Code_Target_Numeral` to your imports. This makes Isabelle's code generator use arbitrary-precision integers of the target language (in case of `value`, that's ML and its GMP-based integers) instead of the inefficient successor notation. As a side effect, this also prints natural numbers in a nicer way.
3. You can add the following code to your theory, which changes the way the `value` command displays natural numbers:

Code:

```
lemma Suc_numeral_bit0: "Suc (numeral (Num.Bit0 n)) = numeral (Num.Bit1 n)"
  by (subst Suc_numeral) simp

lemma Suc_numeral_bit1: "Suc (numeral (Num.Bit1 n)) = numeral (Num.Bit0 (n + Num.One))"
  by (subst Suc_numeral) simp

lemmas [code_post] = 
  One_nat_def [symmetric] Suc_numeral_bit0 Suc_numeral_bit1 Num.Suc_1 Num.arith_simps
```

Note that the `value` command is a diagnostic command only. It is mainly used for quick plausibility tests and debugging of code generation setups, and getting it to work can sometimes be tricky.

By default, `value` relies on the code generator, i.e. Isabelle needs to know how to generate executable code for the expression, and if it cannot do that, `value` will probably fail. (It can sometimes also fall back to some other strategies, normalisation by evaluation or evaluation by simplification, but those usually don't provide useful output)

I'm just telling you this so that you know what to expect from the `value` command and don't get the impression that this is some integral part of Isabelle that people use all the time.

Comment: Wow, may I ask how you learned all this stuff about Isabelle? Did you dig through the manual(s)? That seems an tedious (but impressive) task, as I found parts of them are difficult to read.

Comment: I've been working with that system for over five years, and I've been working at a chair at the TU Munich that co-develops Isabelle for a few years now as well. I haven't actually read a lot of the manuals; they are helpful, but much of it isn't really stuff you absolutely *need* to know as a user. Most of it you just pick up as you use the system, or by asking other people.